# HomeKit Problems on my MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, homekit

I have a Mac Book Pro Catalina 10.15.7. I will upgrade soon, but I cannot get Home App or Home Kit Assistant to function now.
The same Home apps work on my iPhone, but on my MacBook Pro the apps open but have no available functions beyond that. Not even a (+) button to add devices appears in the Home apps on my MacBook. It just hangs there on my screen like it's in a coma or something. Any known fixes?